# How to commit an animation only when score is at 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'll explain well:

I have a score called nScore

so when score is at zero "0"

I would like to make this animation commit - Below is what i tried, all i get is errors! nScore is an int.

```
- (IBAction)skipLevel:(id)sender {

 if ([nScore = 0]) {

    _buyDimsMain.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight     forView:_buyDimsMain cache:YES];
    _buyDimsMain.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
} 
else {

// Nothing

}
```

Please help

Comment: What about this doesn't work? Your edit mentions "all i get is errors" - what kinds of errors? Be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid Objective-C (or valid C):

```
if ([nScore = 0]) {
```

It has two problems.  The first is that you used `=`, which is the assign operator, instead of `==` which is the equivalence operator.  The second is the brackets are incorrect because you are not doing anything involving a selector.

You want to say:

```
if (nScore == 0) {
    // ... your animation code here ...
} else {
    // ... no animating here ...
}
```

Comment: THANKS and how will i do that if its below "19" BELOW 19?

Comment: Um, `if (nScore < 19) { ... }` ??